# get row numbers for a cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, count

From my table I want to get the number of each row. For example, if I have 5 rows, I want to get 1,2,3,4,5.
I have this method, but I get only the number 1:

```java
private void listaAvvio() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
    final List<Dettaglio1> dettagli1 = new ArrayList<Dettaglio1>();
    String tabella_op = "SELECT .....";
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(tabella_op, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        Dettaglio1 d1 = new Dettaglio1();
        d1.id = cur.getString(0);
        d1.FIELD1= cur.getString(1);
        d1.FIELD2= cur.getString(2);
        d1.FIELD3= cur.getString(3);
        d1.NUMBER_OF_SINGLE_ROW++;
        dettagli1.add(d1);
    }
    cur.close();
    db.close();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `Dettaglio1` object in every loop iteration, so the `NUMBER_OF_SINGLE_ROW` in that object is always the same.

You have to use a separate variable to remember the row number:

```java
int row_no = 0;
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    Dettaglio1 d1 = new Dettaglio1();
    d1.id = cur.getString(0);
    ...
    row_no++;
    d1.NUMBER_OF_SINGLE_ROW = row_no;
    dettagli1.add(d1);
}
```